# Discord bot sending a wrong message after the user sends the wrong answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just started discord.js and the math thing keeps bugging me. It sends me a wrong event after the user sends the wrong answer and I need a help because after it sends the wrong event it loops here:

[image]

```
    const error9 = new ME()
        .setTitle('Answer The Question')
        .setDescription(`❗**| ${message.author}, here is your equation:\n\`Operator count ${operator_amount}, level ${level}\`\n\`\`\`fix\n${equation} = ...\`\`\`You have 30 seconds to solve it.**`)
        .setColor(config.colors.answer)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() });

    message.reply({
        embeds: [error9]
    }
    ).then(msg => {
        cd.add(message.author.id);
        let collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => parseInt(m.content) === answer && m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 6000, max: 1 });
        let correct = false;
        collector.on('collect', () => {
            cd.add(message.author.id);
            correct = true;
            const timeDiff = Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp;
            const ans1 = new ME()
                .setTitle('Yey you got the answer~')
                .setDescription(`✅ **| ${message.author}, your answer is correct! It took you ${timeDiff / 1000}s!\n\`\`\`fix\n${equation} = ${answer}\`\`\`**`)
                .setColor(config.colors.correct)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() });

            return message.channel.send({
                embeds: [ans1]
            })

        });
        collector.once('end', () => {

            const ans2 = new ME()
                .setTitle('Aweee Time Out~')
                .setDescription(`❎ **| ${message.author}, timed out. The correct answer is:\n\`\`\`fix\n${equation} = ${answer}\`\`\`**`)
                .setColor(config.colors.no)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() });

            if (!correct) {
                msg.delete();
                message.channel.send({ embeds: [ans2] })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

}

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: discord.js v14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `filter` doesn't work. If you're using discord.js v13 or older, you'll need to know that all `Collector` related classes and methods (both `.create*()` and `.await*()`) takes a single object parameter which also includes the `filter`.

Change your collector's options to this:

```js
let collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter: (m) =>
    parseInt(m.content) === answer && m.author.id === message.author.id,
  time: 6000,
  max: 1,
});
```